# OSGi: how to properly install a resolution answer Map<Resource,List<Wire>>?

Tags: java, osgi, resolver, bnd, bndtools

Hello and good evening,

I have been experimenting a bit with OSGi using Eclipse IDE and the Bndtools plugin.

I made a bundle and created a Component in a package of the bundle.
I made my own `ResolveContext` in that Component and made sure that the `Resolver` would be able to solve my problem.

When calling the `Resolver.resolve(ResolveContext)`-method, a `Map<Resource,List<Wire>>` is returned in case of a solution found.

In my case, I manipulated the problem so that only 1 Resource/Bundle has to be installed, but I don't really understand the answer I am getting from the `Resolver`.

I am getting back a Map with 2 entries:

**1):** org.bram.package.MyComponent$2@10c23f49 [org.bram.package.MyComponent$1@792102f3 -> [org.organisation.types.domotics version=0.12.1]]

**2):** org.organisation.types.domotics version=0.12.1=[]

Note that `org.bram.package.MyComponent` is the Component which I have made and where the Resolver is used in.
The naming of the `Resources` is not important, I just don't really get what this answer means and how to act on it.

To make this resolution complete, should I simply install the bundle `org.organisation.types.domotics` version `0.12.1` (which I can get from my Repositories)?

If more information is needed, please ask and I will try to provide it in as much detail as possible.

Thank you

Comment: Is there a special reason why you use the resolver directly? Normally you create a bndrun file where you specify the repository as well as initial requirements/ bundles and bndtools computes the runbundles as a result of the resolve process.

Comment: Hey Christian, 
there is a special reason why I'm using it directly. That was part of the experience in digging into OSGi. The Resolver must be called from withing the Component (and thus at runtime) when a certain event took place. Good comment, but yes it is on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the requirements you initially put into the resolver as well as the repository. So it is a bit hard to tell.

What I assume is that you put the bundle of MyComponent as a requirement into the resolve process and it tells you that you need to install your bundle as well as the domotics types bundle to achieve a closure.

Comment: I did not specify the requirements I initially put because I think it is not important in this case (correct me if I'm wrong). The reason for it not being necessary is because wheter or not the result of the Resolver is correct, I want to understand what this result means and how it should be handled.

Let's assume that the returned Map of the resolve process is correct. It contains those 2 entries. The first entry gives my own Resource (the bundle where the Resolver got called) and a List<Wire> with 1 wire. The second entry gives the Resource that is given in the Wire.

See next post..

Comment: What my question actually is here is: in case of this resolution answer, what should be done to fulfill the framework?

Should I only install the new Resources given by the Map?
Should I install the new Resources given by the Map ànd create the Wires given with each Resource and add them to that Resource (although no clue if this is even a thing).

Do you understand where I'm going to? I just want to process the answer of the Resolver assuming it is completely correct.

Thanks for the reaction!

Comment: I just re-read your comment and a little note:
the bundle of MyComponent is not added as a requirement. The requirement that is added to the ResolveContext is the org.organisation.types.domotics-package.

This package itself then has 1 requirement and that is for an osgi.ee namespace and a JavaSE version of 1.8. This is already supplied by the framework bundle so that requirement is met when comparing to the getWirings-method in the ResolveContext.